# Prevent Chrome from downloading SVG sprite twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to migrate from one SVG file per icon to a single SVG sprite for all those icons. I would like that sprite to be only loaded once.

Google Chrome, however, seems to re-load the file every time I try to append an icon to the document. How to prevent this?

Below is a reduced test case. Open the "network" tab in dev tools, filter by "sprite", and click "run". You'll notice Google Chrome will attempt to load "sprite.svg" twice, while Firefox will only do it once.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  foo.innerHTML = [
    '<svg role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 100 100">',
    '<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#foo">',
    '</use>'
  ].join('');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<svg role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#foo"></use>
</svg>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: your example craps out, but most likely it's cached and not really (physically) loading twice. Devtools still logs it for debugging... If it is loading twice, check the devtool's `[x] Disable Cache` option.

Comment: @dandavis with or without "disable cache" option the file is loaded twice (see attached screenshot of dev tools)

Comment: You probably don't want to use SVG sprites since SVGs do not have expensive headers and with HTTP/2.0 the number of requests sent don't make a difference anymore because it's all sent over the same socket.

Comment: @mash well, I don't have the luxury of HTTP/2.0

Comment: You could work around the issue by making sure the SVG is being cached or by using a service worker.

Comment: servers can affecting caching as well, make sure the headers are reasonable and that direct browsing serves up a cache. If it does, then perhaps you've found a bug. Can you use a BlobURL w/SVG? if so, you can fetch the sprite once and "serve" it locally to content